# Missing QStackedWidget on Ruby

Tags: ruby, qt, qtruby

I'm trying to get Qt on Ruby to work, but I have problem with QStackedWidget - it seems missing on Qt4 for Ruby.
This code:

`self.stacked_widgets = Qt::QStackedWidget.new(self)`

causes:

> uninitialized constant Qt::QStackedWidget (NameError)

Is there any workaround for this? I'm using the qtbindings gem, maybe there is something else or other control that can behave like a container for widgets and displaying one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

It's Qt::StackedWidget not Qt::QStackedWidget (other classes also Qt::PushButton, Qt::Label...)